# How do I back up Outlook 2019 (desktop) - all profiles and content (emails, calendar etc)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup

I am about to reformat my computer. I'd like to have Outlook 2019 (desktop) set up in the same way as it is now!

This means, the same email accounts (I have several), the same data, email folders attached etc

The options in Outlook seem to be about exporting emails. Whilst I do want my files backed up (the .pst and .ost files), this would still mean re-adding all the profiles (including rules, signatures etc).

Is there a simple way to export Outlook so I can re-import it? Is there a way to "image" what Outlook is currently set as so I can apply it to another machine?

The goal is to not have to manually re-enter every account (profile), set up each signature, re-attach existing pst files etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export and backup a user's Outlook profile, using [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1889-outlook-export-backup-profile.html) article:

> #### How To Export And Backup User Outlook Profile?
>
> 1. Close Microsoft Outlook → Open the *Run...* dialog via <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
> 2. *Open*: `regedit` → OK → Approve the UAC prompt
> 3. Navigate to:
>
>    - Outlook 2007 and 2010:
>
>      ```
>      HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WindowsMessaging Subsystem\Profiles
>      ```
>    - Outlook 2013:
>
>      ```
>      HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles
>      ```
> 4. Right-click the `Profiles` key [folder] → Export
>
>    1. Navigate to where the exported registry key will be saved
>    2. *File Name*: Name the exported registry key
>    3. Save

Your `.pst` file contains all email and email folders, contacts, and calendars, and you may find that Outlook 365 keeps data in the PST file.

- *I cannot guarantee this, but after installing new drives in my Desktop computer and reinstall Windows, when I set up Outlook 365 it was very easy (`.pst` file recovered to the new install).*

Comment: All versions of Outlook use `.pst` & `.ost` databases, w/ the `.pst` databases containing local databases independent of an email server _(e.g. no parity must exist between the `.pst` database and the email server)_, whereas `.ost` databases are a locally mirrored cache of the email server _(e.g. a change occurring in the cache or email server is auto-synced to both, as parity must exist in the cache copy)_. Whereas `.pst` databases can be imported/exported in/out of Outlook, an `.ost` database cannot, nor can an `.ost` be transferred from an old user profile to a new one _(it's only a cache)_

Comment: Personally, I think that this method cannot completely copy Outlook information to another new computer, and it is easy to cause different problems. If possible, it is recommended to export and import the old data to the new computer. Or using Exchange account to sync all your mailbox items.